# Python- Can I use a variable name as an element in a list?

Tags: python, list, variables

In python, is it possible to store a variable in a list? For example, if I want to have a variable depending on it's index in a list, can I do that? I can come up with an alternate solution, but I just wanted to know if something like this was possible.

An example of this scenario would be like sorting a list and having the elements represent user input.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "variable dependent on its index in a list", could you give a use case or example of how you'd expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
side1 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 1: "))
side2 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 2: "))
side3 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 3: "))
side_list = [side1, side2, side3]
```

Yes, this works just fine.